# stopService(intent_with_extras) - how do you read those extras from within the service to stop?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have a Service that can be stopped in multiple ways. Whenever I call stopService(Intent), I pass an intent with some extras. How do you retrieve those extras?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the intent that stops the service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948578/how-to-get-the-intent-that-stops-the-service-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override `onStartCommand()` in your `Service` this is how you get a reference to the incoming intent from `startService`.

In this case you would have a special action in your intent to tell the service to stop itself. You add extras to this intend which can be read in the `onStartCommand()` method.

**Sample Code**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
         final String yourExtra = intent.getStringExtra(YOUR_EXTRA_ID);
         // now you can e.g. call the stopSelf() method but have the extra information
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

*Every time you call `context.startService(Intent)` `onStartCommand()` will be called. If the service is already running a new service isn't created but `onStartCommand` is still called. This is how you can get a new intent with extras to a running service.*

Comment: you mention a reference to the incoming intent from startService, do you mean stopService? Do you have a basic example?

Comment: every time you call context.startService(Intent) startCommand will be called. If the service is already running a new service isn't created but startCommand is still called.  This is how you can get a new intent to a running service.  Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? The issue of reading extras from a stopService request is not addressed.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the extras are not passed with the intent when stopService is called. As a workaround, simply call startService(Intent) and stopService(Intent) right after one another.

Example code from Activity:

`Intent j = new Intent(SocketToYa.this, AccelerometerDataSocket.class);
    j.putExtra("com.christophergrabowski.sockettoya.DestroyService", true);
    startService(j);
    stopService(j);`

In Service.onStartCommand,

`intent.hasExtra("com.christophergrabowski.sockettoya.DestroyService")`

will evaluate to true, and you will destroy your service the way intended by the API (i.e., by calling stopService, which will in turn call OnDestroy after onStartCommand is called).

Comment: Don't like this as this could maybe lead to a race condition if the onDestroy is called faster than the onStartCommand or am I wrong? I read somewhere that the intendet way is to use startService() for all communication with the service, including to stop the service (with extras).

Comment: In the documentation of `onStartCommand()` however it says not to use `startService()` for small messages to the service because there is a larger overhead (life-cycle).

Answer (score 1):

> My suggetion is that use static member in class that extends Activity for passing information to service & it in service as normal static member access in outside class

Please don't do this unless you have no other option.  You should try to use the mechanisms built into the framework for passing data, and not use `public static` fields unless there is no other choice.  Read the `Service` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use an Intent with a "shutdown" action with Context.startService()?

That is, send an Intent with a shutdown action and extras to Service.onStartCommand(), decide how to shutdown based on the extras, then use Service.stopSelf() to stop the service.

I agree this isn't a great solution, since it potentially starts the service in order to shut it down.  I would still like to hear of the "correct" way (if one exists) of doing this with Context.stopService().

Answer (score -1):

You can not write

> getIntent()

method in a class extending Service. So I think using getExtra() won't work.
My suggetion is that use static member in class that extends Activity for passing information to service & it in service as normal static member access in outside class i.e.

> Classname.yourobject

.
see this link for other option
http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

Comment: "To share primitive data between Activities/Services in an application, use Intent.putExtras()"

I did this, now I want to retrieve them in onDestroy() for my service.

Comment: while you still cant use getIntent you can still get a handle on your Intent with startCommand.

Comment: Does not make sense to use static members for basic data types. Usage of Intents and Extras (whenever possible) for communication between Services/Activities is common Android practice. Answer from schwiz looks more useful to me.