# How to get the intent that stops the service in android

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am using `stopService()` to stop the service . and I want to send Extra data with the intent . how to retrieve this extra data in the service ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stopService(intent\_with\_extras) - how do you read those extras from within the service to stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693943/stopserviceintent-with-extras-how-do-you-read-those-extras-from-within-the-s)

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK, this `Intent` is not delivered to the `Service` in any fashion.

Instead of `stopService()`, you can use `startService()` to pass your extras, and include something in there that causes your service to call `stopSelf()`. This will have the net effect of calling `stopService()` *and* supplying extra data at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question but, if anyone's looking for an  alternative, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Service` for stopping the service and then send broadcast to this `receiver` from all over your app. Here, you can get all the information from the `intent` sent to the `receiver`. Within the `receiver`, simply call `stopSelf()`.