# Get Intent passed to stopService(intent) in Service

Tags: android, service, android-ondestroy

I have a requirement to detect source of destroying service.
I am using intent and extra while calling

stopService(intent).

But where to catch this intent in Service class to act upon.
Already gone through android docs, nothing helpful found. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to get that `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare  , thanks for quick response. Any other solution for this problem ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948578/how-to-get-the-intent-that-stops-the-service-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I believe Mark Murphy when he said it isn't possible. As an alternative, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Service` for stopping the service and then send broadcast to this `receiver` from all over your app. Here, you can get all the information from the `intent` sent to the `receiver`. Within the `receiver`, simply call `stopSelf()`.