# Get intent in Service return NullPointerException

Tags: android, service

I create Service and call it from `MainActivity.class` with put string extra to intent but when I call `getStringExtra` in onStartCommand, it returns **NullPointerException**

Here is my code:

**MainService.class :**

```
public class MainService extends Service { 
private WindowManager wm;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;  
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {    
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();       
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mView != null) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.removeView(mView);
    }
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);      
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final String quote = intent.getStringExtra("quote");
    Log.d("datastring",quote);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

In MainActivity.class I called :

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class);
i.putExtra("quote", "dataquote");
stopService(i);
```

How I can get string from MainActivity in MainService?

Comment: We cannot get `intent` from `stopService`. This was asked yesterday too, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191968/get-intent-passed-to-stopserviceintent-in-service/39192026#39192026

Comment: @Shaishav How I can get intent in Service?

Comment: Did you try to use `startService(i)` in `MainActivity.class`, rather than `stopService(i)`?

Comment: @DatNguyen it sample.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer, @ĐờiCơbảnlàBuồn, but if you declare your Service in the manifest properly, then invoking `startService(i)` in your activity with the intent you have above, you should be able to get the `StringExtra` in the `onStartCommand(...)`. If you still receive `NPE` when using 'startService(i)`, please let us know.

Comment: yep, thank you very much. It run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide more data to your `Service` you need to use something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class);
intent.putExtra("quote", "dataquote");
startService(intent);
```

This will start the service and you should be able to get the data `intent` in the `onStartCommand()`. If the `Service` is already running, `onStartCommand()` will still be called with the new `intent`. This is because `Service` components are inherently singleton, so only one instance of a particular service run at a time.

In your case, you are providing the data via `stopService(intent)`. Not only its not possible to get this `intent`, your `Service` will also stop after this statement so, you cannot really do much with the data even if you could have read it.

If you still need to stop your `Service` and pass data at the same time, you should check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191968/get-intent-passed-to-stopserviceintent-in-service/39192026#39192026).